# The error message for this function is vague, can someone explain it?

Tags: python, sqlite

What is wrong with the syntax? I have used print statements inside the function and verified the calling code is sending the correct information to be updated in database. I tried using the `?` placeholders instead of the dictionary but keep getting errors:

```
def update_ticket_record(cal_txt, tr_txt, cust_cbo, addr_cbo, issue_txt, notes_txt,   oid):
conn = sqlite3.connect("my_service.db")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""UPDATE ticket SET
    tick_date = :cal_txt,
    tick_tr = :tr_txt,
    tick_cust = :cust_cbo,
    tick_addr = :addr_cbo,
    tick_issue = :issue_txt,
    tick_notes = :notes_txt,
    WHERE tick_id = :oid""", {
        'cal_txt': cal_txt.get(),
        'tr_txt': tr_txt.get(),
        'cust_cbo': cust_cbo.get(),
        'addr_cbo': addr_cbo.get(),
        'issue_txt': issue_txt.get(),
        'notes_txt': notes_txt.get(1.0, 'end-1c'),
        'oid': oid,
    })

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

```
File "D:\myJournal\database.py", line 96, in update_ticket_record
cur.execute("""UPDATE ticket SET
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is the `,` after `notes_txt`. If you remove that so the query reads `... tick_notes = :notes_txt WHERE tick_id = :oid` then it should work.

The [vague] error is pointing to WHERE being invalid immediately after a `,`.